# ASP.NET core background service to send data through signalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-2017

I'm using signalR to send data to clients from server. What I want to is check data in the table(MSSQL DB) and send the related data to clients through signalR. So I want to create some background service to check database and send data.

I planned to use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

with

```
while(true)
```

loop. How can I create service class to run this method in startup.

Is there any method to use do this task in standard way??

Answer (score 14):

You can use an `IHostedService` and `IHubContext` to accomplish this.

See the doc on background services with ASP.NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1

See the doc on `IHubContext`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Here's an example of using both together:

https://github.com/davidfowl/UT3/blob/fb12e182d42d2a5a902c1979ea0e91b66fe60607/UTT/Scavenger.cs

And the wire up:

https://github.com/davidfowl/UT3/blob/fb12e182d42d2a5a902c1979ea0e91b66fe60607/UTT/Startup.cs#L46

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a similar implementation. I looked at the suggestion by @davidfowl, and it's pretty complete. Nevertheless, I would like to share my approach that will work for simple scenarios where the list of connected users does not need to be persisted.

https://github.com/shernandezp/SignalRServer

By the way,  the previous version of my service (an old one with Net Framework) uses a Thread, which works, but Net Core provides a better implementation.