# SignalR - long running task on start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm looking into starting a long running task when SignalR starts and then sending data from it to the client.

From what I could find the place to run code on startup is inside `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method.

When using `ASP.NET SignalR` I can then send messages to frontend using:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.Send("Admin", "message");
```

In `ASP.NET Core SignalR` the same is achieved by injecting an `IHubContext` [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2).  But I can't use that in the `Configure` method since it is not possible to inject anything into it.

Where can I inject `IHubContext` in a method which is called when SignalR starts so I can start the long running task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET core background service to send data through signalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251688/asp-net-core-background-service-to-send-data-through-signalr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is using a [hosted-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1). You could do something like this:

```cs
internal class MySignalRService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;

    public MySignalRService(IHubContext hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Setup some scheduler to do your job

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

And then

```cs
services.AddHostedService<MySignalRService>();
```